# group data in foreach in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this table

[image]

here's the index function

```
use App\GrantLoanAmount;
use App\LoanAmount;
use App\User;
use App\Profile;

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $defaultAmount = LoanAmount::where('default', 1)->first();
    $grantloanamounts = GrantLoanAmount::with('users','amounts')->get();      
    return view('loan.grant-loan-amounts.index', compact('grantloanamounts'))
                ->with('defaultAmount',$defaultAmount);
}
```

here's my index blade table

```
    @foreach($grantloanamounts as $item)
        @if($item->amounts[0]->amount > $defaultAmount->amount)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $item->users[0]->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->amounts[0]->amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->users[0]->name }}</td>
            <td class="text-right">action buttons</td>
        </tr>
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

How can I group the user name to become look like this?

username
   amount
   amount
   amount

Comment: Go from `Users`->`GrantLoanAmount` instead `GrantLoanAmount->Users`